# Hidden sort indicator on column in QTreeView

Tags: qt

I have QTreeView and I `setSortEnable = true` for it, and all of column show sort indicator, but now I want last column do not show sort indicator, just last column.

Have any idea or solution for my issue..:(

please help
Thanks

Comment: `QHeaderView::setSortIndicatorShown()` function might help.

Comment: it hidden all of indicator on my treeview, I just want ONE. :(..please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QHeaderView` always draws the sorting indicator on a column when data is sorted by this column (if `setSortIndicatorShown` is `true`).

That is why it look like the only way to prohibit drawing of the indicator is to prohibit sorting of the column by left-click.

To prohibit sorting by a certain column you need:
1. create a new class inherited from `QHeaderView` (or use an event filter)
2. reimplement `mouseReleaseEvent`  and `mousePressEvent`
3. use `logicalIndexAt` to indicate that user clicked on the column
4. call `setSectionsClickable(false)` before calling the base method and `setSectionsClickable(true)` after it.

Example:

```
void HeaderView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
  const int index = logicalIndexAt(e->pos());
  if (index == 3) setSectionsClickable(false);
  QHeaderView::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
  setSectionsClickable(true);
}
```

Do the same for `mousePressEvent`.

thus you will prohibit sorting of a certain column

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've three columns and it was necessary to hide the sort indicator of the second column.
Because of I had custom rules of sorting, just got `QHeaderView::sectionClicked` event with `OnHeaderClicked(int column)` slot, and did this:

```
switch (column)
{
    case 0:
        // Custom sorting operations
        break;
    case 1:
        tree_widget_->sortByColumn(-1);
        break;
    case 2:
        // Custom sorting operations
        break;
}
```